# React on function click passed as props with HOC its getting executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

having an issue with the on click the function it generates iterative multiple times, like one-click one time, two-click two times, three-click three times. and so on... What am I doing wrong here? below is the way I have implemented the structure and logic

Comment: you example is not enough. Put a console.log inside your function and see how many times gets excecuted. The problem might be inside PageContainer

Comment: Like I said, As many times I click that button, that many times @BarbuBarbu

Comment: oh and btw, don't listen inside a click method socket.on, that will be reigstered every time!

Comment: You are attaching a new event listener on each click. All of the `.on()` methods are creating a new event listener. So each time the `handleChatItemClicked` method is invoked, new event handlers will be created. And this is why you have the issue.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Okay, so how can I fix this? Can you help?

Comment: Try moving `socket.on("room_leave", ...)` and `socket.on("get_user_room", ...)` to the constructor.

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Can you help me here? How exactly I can do? Please help resolving this

Comment: constructor, or better would be in componentDidMount

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Can you write me a code for your fix? Sorry for asking more but I am kind of trying to understand how it works

Comment: Can you write me a code for that, it would be so helpful for me. @BarbuBarbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you don't really know how react works, but here's dummy example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChatItemClicked = this.handleChatItemClicked.bind(this);
}

handleChatItemClicked = (payload) => {
    this.setState({
        sender_to_receiver_details: payload,
        is_member_selected: true
    });
    socket.emit("room_leave", {
        room_id: this.props.socket_details.room_id,
    })
    socket.emit("get_user_room", payload);
};

componentDidMount() {
    socket.on("get_user_room", (data) => {
        this.props.actions.savingRoomId(data)
    })
    socket.on("room_leave", () => {
        socket.emit("room_join", {
            room_id: this.props.socket_details.room_id,
        })
    })
socket.on("room_join", (data) => {
        })

}
```

Comment: make sure to unsubscribe also, in the componentWillUnmount method. should be somehing like socket.off(''room_join"), etc

Comment: How do I pass `data` in componentDidmount?

Comment: you don't need to. You get all your data from this.state, or this.props

Comment: Okay let . me try

Comment: Quick question, for message on socket.on() where should I place this code? It won't be working If I place it on ComponentDidmount() but it has the same issue of multiple clicks.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: from what I see you still have socket.on inside your click method. also I see it inside if statements. you should remove those from there.

Comment: Here is the code, I've pasted in codesandbox codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dubinsky-3idjk please help me getting the right structure of that file. Seems like I have many wrong configuration. It would really helpful if you are able to re-write the file as per working of socket and message

Comment: Could not find module in path: '../../data/config/urls' relative to '/src/index.js Please add the missing things to the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206848/discussion-between-barbu-barbu-and-xfw).